# Dependency problems while updating Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, apt, updates

I have the following error while trying to update my system:

```
user# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (3.5.0-25.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic depends on linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just missing the update source in update manager. Purge the file,

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic
```